# SAS 9.3 Table Properties (Description)

Tags: sas

I've been looking for a way to value/change a table's description through a program/code instead of the UI.  The table description is on the General tab of the table properties.  Everything I've found shows how to through UI but nothing through code.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually the dataset label.  That can be added a few ways, basically anywhere you write the dataset, or PROC DATASETS.

```
proc datasets lib=work;
  modify want(label="Want Label");
quit;
```

Or

```
data class(label="Class Dataset");
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the quick reply.